# Raise an error when a key is duplicated in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, key

I've created a code that reads in a text file and converts the lines to a dictionary.

How do I raise an error if there is more than one key with the same value? I don't know the value of the particular keys so I need it to check the values itself. Currently it is overwriting the key-value but I would like to know how to check the dictionary keys against each other so i can raise an error message. Thank you

Comment: `if current_key in my_dictionary: # raise error here` should be like something you want.

Comment: Thanks Steve, the problem is .. there's lots of keys, not just one particular value. There could potentially be hundreds of keys

Comment: Oh, iterate through it you mean?

Comment: That's what I had in mind, maybe as you were reading the lines. What code do you have? That might help.

Comment: I don't have anything haha. I just have my dictionary. A file that reads in and is set as a dictionary. I also have sorted it in value. I don't know how to test the keys against each other though... I'm thinking it will need to use reverse?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict.values() method to get all values stored in dictionary, then you can use set() datatype to remove all duplicates and compare it length with original, if it is smaller it means that in your dictionary were duplicates.
Here is an example:

```
d={"key":"val"} #some dictionary
if len(set(d.values())) != len(d.values()):
    raise ValueError("Your error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post the input file and/or the code you are using to create the dictionary? As Steve is also implying through his questions, it might be better to solve the root of the problem rather than simply flag the issue.

For example, it might be helpful to know the value of the keys that are are causing the issue and treat them in some specific way rather than just overwriting. For this, if you are using something like the below code to create your dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = dict(keys, values)
```

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
key_srs = pd.Series(keys)
key_counts = key_srs.groupby(key_srs).count()
duplicate_key_counts = key_counts[key_counts>1]
```

To find the duplicate keys and how many times they have been repeated.

Comment: It's definitely the file. There is more than 1 key the with the same 'name'. I want to be able to handle the errors gracefully though. The pandas might just work!!

Comment: `duplicate_key_counts.index` will give you the keys that are giving you the trouble, though to clarify, what I'm trying to say here that flagging the keys afterwards isn't the best way to go. Instead, it's better to handle the errors gracefully before this, at the time of reading in the file.